# fadeToggle div and then back again

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, back

Sorry if this is a really obvious problem to solve. What I am trying to do is have a div, when selected is replaced with another div with the option to revert "back" to the old div when "back" is clicked.

This is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#display-one").click(function() {
            $("#display-two").fadeToggle();
            $("#display-one").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
#display-two {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    <div id="display-one"><a href="#">Dispay One</a></div>
</div>

<div id="display-two">
<p><a href="#">Display Two</a></p>
<h3>
<div id="back">
<a href="#">back</a>
</div>
</h3>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uL8z87r7/1/

Thanks in advance for any help and tips!
-John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `#back a` to your selector so it will be `$("#display-one, #back a")`

```js
$("#display-one, #back a").click(function() {
  $("#display-two").fadeToggle();
  $("#display-one").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
#display-two {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div id="display-one"><a href="#">Dispay One</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="display-two">
  <p><a href="#">Display Two</a>
  </p>
  <h3>
<div id="back">
<a href="#">back</a>
</div>
</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add listener for the back button

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#display-one,#back").click(function() {
            $("#display-two").fadeToggle();
            $("#display-one").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#display-one, #back").click(function() {
       $("#display-one, #display-two").fadeToggle();
   });
});
```

```css
#display-two {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    <div id="display-one"><a href="#">Dispay One</a></div>
</div>

<div id="display-two">
<p><a href="#">Display Two</a></p>
<h3>
<div id="back">
<a href="#">back</a>
</div>
</h3>
</div>
```